# Conversor de temperatura

Tags: c, c++, tipagem

Quando digito a temperatura em *Fahrenheint* o programa retorna 0 como resultado, onde está o erro?

```
#include <cstdlib>
  #include <iostream>
  #include <conio.h>
  #include <string.h>
  #include <math.h>

  using namespace std;

  int main(int argc, char *argv[])
  {
    float celsius = 0, fah = 0;
    char tecla;

    cout << "Digite a temperatura em C°:"; cin >> celsius;

    fah = (9 * celsius + 160) / 5;

    cout << "Temperatura em F°:" << fah << endl;       

    cout << "Digite a temperatura em F°:"; cin >> fah;

    celsius = (fah - 32) * (5/9);

    cout << "Temperatura em C°:" << celsius << endl;      

    system("PAUSE");
    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

Comment: Reveja a fórmula que você está utilizando para conversão de Fahrenheint  para Celsius

Comment: Alguma das respostas resolveu sua dúvida? Acha que pode aceitar uma delas? Veja o [tour] como fazer isso, se ainda não o fez. Você ajudaria a comunidade identificando qual foi a melhor solução para você. Pode aceitar apenas uma delas. Mas pode votar em qualquer pergunta ou resposta que achar útil no site todo

Answer (score 3):

Sempre que for usar um literal numérico se certifique de ser o literal do tipo certo. No tipo `float` o literal sempre tem um ponto decimal e termina com um `f` ou `F`. Sua divisão de 5 por 9 está usando inteiros, então 5 dividido por 9 dá 0 e aí tudo que se multiplique por 0 dá 0.

Você não precisa nem declarar o tipo se usar o literal certo. O compilador infere pra você.

Cuidado para usar 5.0 apenas ou fazer a conta direto, se não usar o sufixo `f` o tipo será `double` e em alguns caos pode dar um resultado ligeiramente diferente. Pode não afetar este caso, mas aprenda como fazer certo sempre.

mantendo sua fórmula do jeito correto e simplificado:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    auto celsius = 0.0f;
    cout << "Digite a temperatura em C°:"; cin >> celsius;
    auto fah = (9 * celsius + 160) / 5;
    cout << "Temperatura em F°:" << fah << endl;       
    cout << "Digite a temperatura em F°:"; cin >> fah;
    cout << "Temperatura em C°:" << (fah - 32) * (5.0f / 9) << endl;      
}
```

Veja [funcionando no **ideone**](https://ideone.com/6KPARZ). E [no **repl.it**](https://repl.it/join/axwnexkm-maniero). Também [coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/CPP/Math/DivisionFloat.cpp).

Answer (score 1):

Para converter *Fahrenheit* em *Celsius*, subtraia 32 e divida por 1,8.

> °C = (°F − 32) ÷ 1, 8

**Veja Exemplo:**

```
#include <cstdlib>
#include <iostream>
#include <conio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <math.h>

using namespace std;
int main(int argc, char *argv[]){

    float celsius = 0, fah = 0;
    char tecla;

    cout << "Digite a temperatura em Celsius:"; cin >> celsius;

    fah = (9 * celsius + 160) / 5;

    cout << "Temperatura em Fahrenheit:" << fah << endl;       


    cout << "Digite a temperatura em Fahrenheit:"; cin >> fah;

    celsius = (fah - 32) / 1.8;

    cout << "Temperatura em Celsius:" << celsius << endl;      

    system("PAUSE");
    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Answer (score 1):

Você esta de Confundindo com a Formula e o tipo de variavel usada, es aqui o codigo

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <string.h>
#include <math.h>

using namespace std;

int main(int argc, char *argv[]){

float celsius = 0, fah = 0;
char tecla;

  cout << "Digite a temperatura em C°:"; cin >> celsius;

  fah = (9 * celsius + 160) / 5;

  cout << "Temperatura em F°:" << fah << endl;       

  cout << "Digite a temperatura em F°:"; cin >> fah;

  celsius = (fah - 32) / (1.8);

  cout << "Temperatura em C°: " << celsius << endl;      

  system("PAUSE");
  return EXIT_SUCCESS;
  }
```

Você Estava Errando Justamente nessa Linha
 **celsius = (fah - 32) / (1.8);**